# Returning route geometry using OpenTripPlanner API

Tags: routing, api, opentripplanner

I already managed to return geometries of Isochrones using the API as follows:

```
https://sampleserver.com/otp/routers/myrouterid/isochrone?algorithm=accSampling&mode=WALK&walkSpeed=1.11&cutoffSec=900&precisionMeters=10&date=2017/11/22&time=14:00:00&maxWaitingTime=20&maxWalkDistance=1000&transfers=5&offRoadDistanceMeters=100&fromPlace=44.097088542141,14.5792197160854
```

Now I'd like to also return requested routes via OpenTripPlanner REST-API as line geometry which can be loaded into a GIS.

```
https://sampleserver.com/otp/routers/myrouterid/plan?fromPlace=44.170960,14.5311114&toPlace=44.127964,14.603506&time=14:00:00&date=2017/11/22&mode=CAR
```

returns the route as JSON, but not its geometry.

I already tried different URLs as described in the API-Docs here: http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.0.0/resources.html, but so far I wasn't able to return a route geometry.

Is it possible to return the geometry of a route using OpenTripPlanner API and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed a PlugIn for QGIS which can do this: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OpenTripPlannerPlugin/. *It decodes the polylinestrings as mentioned in my first answer.*

Your OTP-Server needs to be accessible without a proxy or authentification; enter its URL including the part to the router in "General Settings" tab (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/otp/router/myrouter/`)

Then choose your one or two point layers containing the starts and stops. Note the checkbox "Create only Routes for matching Fields" if you wish to create a matrix or create all routes from source to target. Then choose your desired settings and hit run.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`plan` resource returns an [encoded polylinestring](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm).

This can be turned into 'actual geometry' using scripts from this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217274/how-to-decode-the-google-directions-api-polylines-field-into-lat-long-points-in/22737305

There are working ports for python, VBA, Java, ...

These can be used to create a GeoJSON file of the route.

Answer (score 2):

If you are an R user you could use https://docs.ropensci.org/opentripplanner/

You can then save out the results in a QGIS compatible format

```
otpcon = otp_connect()
mydata = otp_plan(otpcon, from, to)
sf::write_sf(mydata,"mydata.gpkg")
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my [Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OpenTripPlannerPlugin/) I made a [responsive processing tool for QGIS](https://github.com/mkoenigb/QGIS_Processingtools/blob/master/OtpRoutes.py), which does exactly what I need, but cannot post it here due to `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 32412.`, so just follow the link....

PS: I still have an open question to improve it, in case you know the answer: [Changing feature attribute just after adding via QgsFeatureSink](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388546/changing-feature-attribute-just-after-adding-via-qgsfeaturesink)

Answer (score 0):

I basically wrap this thing and added in an existing python site-package called rasta with an easy-to-use class. Here is an example:

```py
from rasta.navigate_with_otp import GetOtpRoute

my_otp_nav = GetOtpRoute(
    start_coord="48.81941, 9.27212",
    end_coord="48.78153, 9.20517",
    time="03:00:00", # Optinal, if not provided then it uses the current time
    date="2020/12/25", # Optinal, if not provided then it uses the current date
    MAPBOX_API_KEY=MAPBOX_API_KEY, # Necessary, only if you want to visualize in the map
    output_map_path="temporary_map", # To save the output kepler map
    mode="TRANSIT,WALK" # If not provided, then assuime the " Transit and walk"
)
```

A notebooks is also available [here](https://github.com/ikespand/rasta/blob/master/example/otp_navigation_notebook.ipynb), which shows dataframe and visualisation as well.